# I am using JAVAFX8,and i am using Calendar Picker from JFXTras

Tags: javafx

I am using JAVAFX8,and i developed Calendar picker from JFXTRAS but i need a listener to select highlighted date when we click with mouse on highlighted date.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information and the code you have tried so that we can help?

Comment: Can you clarify this question? What do you mean by "I need a listener to select highlighted date" - isn't a highlighted date already selected? If not, what do you mean? "... when we click with mouse on highlighted date" Do you mean that exactly, i.e. if the user clicks on the date which is already highlighted/selected? Typically in this case the selection wouldn't change. If that says what you actually mean, why do you want to respond to this?

Comment: i am highlighting some dates in calendar picker,when we click on highlighted date we have to retreive that date.

Comment: For Example : i am highlighting mar-17,18,19,20 dates in calendar picker with highlighted observable list,my requirement is when we click on 17 th date we have to get that date and we have to show the events on that date.

Comment: I used the Below code it is working fine.

Comment: added EventeFiltter on Calendar picker my issue is resolved.